# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} { \sqrt{n^2 +n^{\alpha}} } - n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

> For each rational $\alpha$ find 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} { \sqrt{n^2 +n^{\alpha}} } - n$$
>   Only elementary inequalities are allowed

**Hint:** Look at $\alpha < 1, 1 \le \alpha < 2, \alpha \ge 2$

By rationalization, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} { \sqrt{n^2 +n^{\alpha}} } - n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{ \sqrt{1+n^{\alpha-2}}+1}.$$ From here it is clear that for $\alpha \ge 2$ the expressions $\to \infty$ and for $ \alpha =1 $ the limit =1 and as for $ \alpha \lt 1$ the limit is $0$. I am stuck for the case $1\leq \alpha <2$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are much more likely to get answers rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. And please use mathjax properly That's been done for you this time.

Comment: seems you could start by using the trick $$\sqrt{n^2+n^\alpha}-n=(\sqrt{n^2+n^\alpha}-n)\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n^\alpha}+n}{\sqrt{n^2+n^\alpha}+n}=\frac{n^\alpha}{\sqrt{n^2+n^\alpha}+n}.$$

Comment: yeah i got that and proceeded naturally to $\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1+n^{\alpha-2}} + 1} $ clearly for $\alpha$=1 the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$ and for $\alpha \ge 2$ the limit is $\infty$

Comment: Indeed, furthermore this also shows that the limit is $0$ for $\alpha <1$. By the way you should edit your question and add these observations. This is appreciated in MSE (to show some effort) and it will higher the chance you get an answer.

Comment: Finally, note that for $\alpha \in (1,2)$, you might be able to use l'hospital.

Comment: L'hospital is not allowed on this question

Comment: @Adi ok, then there should be another trick. I insist that if you want to stop getting downvoted (and want to avoid your question being closed), you should **edit your question** with what you told me in the comment.

Comment: Not sure I understand the trouble if $\alpha\in(1,2)$. Since $\alpha<2$, $$n^{\alpha-2}\to0$$ hence $$\sqrt{1+n^{\alpha-2}}\to1$$ hence $$\sqrt{1+n^{\alpha-2}}+1\to2$$ On the other hand,, since $\alpha>1$,  $$n^{\alpha-1}\to+\infty$$ hence $$\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1+n^{\alpha-2}}+1}\sim\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}2\to+\infty$$ The last LHS above is a formula in your question.

Comment: Apart from that, I fully concur with @Surb's admonestations and, AFAIAC, I plan to vote in consequence.

Comment: @Did I think you answered the last part of the question.

Comment: @Surb "I am stuck for the case 1≤α<2" This seems to be the question. Did I miss something? Yes, I left the case $\alpha=1$ to the OP... :-)

Comment: Even more elementary: for every $\alpha$ in $(1,2)$, $$\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1+n^{\alpha-2}}+1}\geqslant\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1+1}+1}\geqslant\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}3\to+\infty$$

Comment: @Did OP knows the limit when $\alpha = 1$. Initially, OP did not state anything he observed in his question. Then I noticed that OP indeed put some efforts before posting (but did not mention it). Then the question got closed, OP edited and I formatted to make clear where OP is stuck. From the comments, I understand that the only part OP was missing is the case you just answered. All in all, if you post your last comment as an answer, I will upvote it and hopefully OP will accept it.

Comment: @Surb Done. $ $

Comment: It is not clear why you are giving others a hint, if you do not know how to solve the problem. Similarly, it is not clear why you are forbidding anyone from using L'Hopital's rule (in the comments).

Comment: @CarlMummert I guess this was a homework assignment and the hint was given with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary approach: for every $\alpha$ in $(1,2)$, $$n^{\alpha-2}\leqslant1\qquad\text{and}\qquad n^{\alpha-1}\to+\infty$$ hence $$\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1+n^{\alpha-2}}+1}\geqslant\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}{\sqrt{1+1}+1}\geqslant\frac{n^{\alpha-1}}3\to+\infty$$

Comment: Amusing revenge downvote... MSE will never change, I guess.